# difference between a == 10 || 20 and a == 10 || a == 20 these two

Tags: logical-operators

let s = 10;

```
if(s == 10 || s == 20){
  console.log(s)
}

if( s == 10 || 20){
  console.log(s)
}
```

// What is the defrence between these two conditions

I tried both condition and the output were the same. So what's the difference between them. It may be the stupid question but i want to konw the difference. Thanks in advance

Comment: `s == 10 || 20` says is `s == 10` true?  And if it isn't then is `20` true?  And `20` is true so the if statement will always be true.  The reason they both act the same is because the second condition is never checked ifg the first one is true.  Try setting s to 11 and see the difference.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the language tag.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one IF (s == 10 || s == 20) the entire IF condition is TRUE if either boolean expression s == 10 OR s == 20 is TRUE.  As this is processed, once the first boolean expression is TRUE the condition is met so the s==10 triggered that and console.log(s) was called.

In the second condition ( s == 10 || 20) the entire condition is TRUE if either boolean expression s==10 OR 20 is TRUE.  It succeeds for the same reason as stated above.  Typically a non-zero value means TRUE so in your programming language having a value of twenty there is the same as if you had the keyword TRUE there so no syntax error was thrown, even though it really does not make any sense and is indeed a logic error in the code (assuming you meant it to work the same as the first example).

This is why code reviews are a good idea.